# How to write database query in extended session class codeigniter 3

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I have extended codeigniter native Session class and  put it in

`application/libraries/Session/MY_Session.php`

In my extended class I would like to write a query to fetch data from  database. It is giving error like

> Fatal error: Call to a member function from() on string in  .../application/libraries/Session/MY_Session.php

Below is my extended Session class

```
<?php

require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Driver.php';
require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Session/Session.php';
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {        
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);

    }
    protected function _configure(&$params)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->db->from('tbl_users');
        $CI->db->where("email", "xyz.com");
        $row = $CI->db->get()->row_array();
        if($row)
            $expiration = 180;
        else
             $expiration = config_item('sess_expiration');
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you try this: `$query = $CI->db->get_where('tbl_users', array('email' => "xyz.com"), $limit, $offset);` or replace `$CI->db->from(...)` with `$CI->db->get('tbl_users')`

Comment: Now am getting error like 

Message: Call to a member function get_where() on string

Filename: Session/MY_Session.php

Comment: Load `$this->load->database();` class before making a db query.

Comment: That worked @VirenPanchal . Thank you so much.